# Oracle transpose every "n" columns into a row

Tags: oracle, transpose

I've a SQL which creates few metrics in below format and I want to transpose them into rows at every 'n'-th column for example, cut every 4 columns and convert into rows. Also there can be 'n' number of  columns i.e 12, 20, 40, etc (multiples of 4 in my case).

I need to load these rows into a table.

Find below example,

[image]

Sample data.

```
SELECT 1 AS col1, 'Total number of Customer' AS col2, 100 AS col3, NULL AS col4,
       1.1 AS col5, 'Total active customers' AS col6, 50 AS col7, NULL AS col8,
       1.2 AS col9, 'Total inactive customers' AS col10, 50 AS col11,ABC AS col12
  FROM DUAL;
```

---

**Note**: There could be `n` number of columns. It can be 12, 40 (multiples of 4 in my case).

Comment: One tip : Add text data for data/results. Please don't post images. I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a union of the groups of 4 columns:

```
SELECT Col1 AS "S.No", Col2 AS "Metric Name", Col3 AS Count, Col4 AS Example
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1
```

I wonder how you ended up with such a table, but in any case I recommend using the output of the above query as the new version of your data moving forward.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My bad that I didn't mention that there could be 'n' number of columns. It can be 12, 40 (multiples of 4 in my case)

Comment: To handle an arbitrary number of columns you will need dynamic SQL, which is above my pay grade.  Though, you could easily add selects to the above union query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

```
with cte as (
    SELECT 1 AS col1, 'Total number of Customer' AS col2, 100 AS col3, NULL AS col4,
           1.1 AS col5, 'Total active customers' AS col6, 50 AS col7, NULL AS col8,
           1.2 AS col9, 'Total inactive customers' AS col10, 50 AS col11,ABC AS col12
      FROM DUAL
)
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from cte
union all
select col5, col6, col7, col8 from cte
union all
select col9, col10, col11, col12 from cte
order by 1
;
```

However, this looks like the sort of format which should really be handled in the displaying client rather than in SQL.

---

> " there could be 'n' number of columns. It can be 12, 40 (multiples of 4 in my case) "

Then it is even more the case that it should be handled in the client. Because the only way to implement an arbitrary projection is to use dynamic SQL: write a PL/SQL function to generate a bespoke SQL statement for a paramterised query and number of columns. The snag is, you will have to return a weak ref cursor, because the projection is unknown at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My bad that I didn't mention that there could be 'n' number of columns. It can be 12, 40 (multiples of 4 in my case)